# Does the Poincaré-Hopf index theorem imply that on the sphere every tangent vector field has a singularity?

Tags: differential-topology

We know that $\chi(M) = 2 = \sum_{x_0 \in \text{Sing}(X)}I(x_o,X)$, where $X$ is any tangent vector and $x_0$ is a singularity. I mean,  the sum is over all singularities of $X$, an arbitrary tangent vector field.

Then, once this sum is equal $2$ for every vector field $X$, all of these vectors has at least a point where vanishes.

Is this right?

Comment: Yes. This special case is known as the hairy ball theorem.

Comment: By "any" vector field, you presumably mean _continuous_ and with _finitely many zeros_. Those are common "standing hypotheses" in topology, but it's important to be aware you're not really speaking of arbitrary vector fields.

Comment: yes, I got it @AndrewD.Hwang, I would have to be more clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it makes more sense to say 'zero' rather than 'singularity', but yes. If $X$ is a vector field on $M$ which has isolated singularities, and $\chi(M) \neq 0$, then $X$ must have at least one singularity. Otherwise, the sum over singularities is empty and hence zero which is impossible as $\chi(M) \neq 0$.